# A spring-boot embedded tomcat web app with actuator enabled gets 404 response from tomcat when deployed to kubernetes

Tags: java, spring-boot, tomcat

I have an issue with a spring boot web application running in k8 that is not reproducible on my local dev running with exactly the same configuration - I get a 404 hitting http://localhost:8080/actuator only when running in k8.

Summary of configuration:

- spring-boot-starter version 2.7.10.
- The only endpoints provided by the tomcat web server is the set of actuator endpoints.
- On k8 java version is 1.8.0_345; local dev machine 1.8.0_151

*application.yaml*

```
server:
  port: 8080
  error:
    whitelabel:
      enabled: true
    include-exception: true
    include-message: always
    include-binding-errors: always
    include-stacktrace: always
  servlet:
    context-path: '/'


logging:
  level:
    org:
      apache:
        tomcat: DEBUG
        catalina: DEBUG
      springframework:
        web:
          filter:
            CommonsRequestLoggingFilter: DEBUG

# actuator
management:
  endpoints:
    enabled-by-default: true
    web.exposure.include: "*"
  endpoint:
    shutdown.enabled: false
    info.enabled: true



hikariCP:
  dataSourceClassName: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDataSource

spring:
  # Preferred JSON mapper to use for HTTP message conversion.
  mvc.converters.preferred-json-mapper: gson
  autoconfigure:
    exclude: org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration
  datasource:
    bet:
      url: someserver
      username: MSSQL_USER
      password: MSSQL_PASS
      hikari:
        poolName: betHikariCP
        maximum-pool-size: 5
        connectionTimeout: 30000
        idleTimeout: 600000
        maxLifetime: 1800000
```

Observed behaviour:

- running locally I can hit the actuator at localhost:8080/actuator but running the same configuration on kubernetes I get a  404 error message when I exec into the pod and run `curl localhost:8080/actuator` - *note this response is coming from Apache Tomcat/9.0.73*

404 Response

```
    <html lang="en">
        <head>
            <title>HTTP Status 404 – Not Found</title>
            <style type="text/css">body {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;} h1, h2, h3, b {color:white;background-color:#525D76;} h1 {font-size:22px;} h2 {font-size:16px;} h3 {font-size:14px;} p {font-size:12px;} a {color:black;} .line {height:1px;background-color:#525D76;border:none;}</style>
        </head>
        <body>
            <h1>HTTP Status 404 – Not Found</h1>
            <hr class="line"/>
            <p>
                <b>Type</b> Status Report</p>
            <p>
                <b>Description</b> The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists.</p>
            <hr class="line"/>
            <h3>Apache Tomcat/9.0.73</h3>
        </body>
    </html>
```

- log output both locally and on kubernetes suggests

  - tomcat starts and binds to port 8080 without error: `Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path ''`
  - the actuator endpoints are stood up. Logger `org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.web.EndpointLinksResolver` outputs `Exposing 13 endpoint(s) beneath base path '/actuator'`
  - I have configured `CommonsRequestLoggingFilter` that will log all requests; and locally this outputs a statement when I hit /actuator locally but it outputs nothing on kubernetes.

Output (local only - on k8 I get nothing):

```
2023-07-14 10:25:23.610 DEBUG PRE-REQUEST: GET /actuator]
2023-07-14 10:25:23.656 DEBUG POST-REQUEST: GET /actuator]
```

Note also that I can put in a bad route locally e.g. actuatorxxx and I still get the PRE and POST log output and the 404 response I get locally is json not html:

```
{
    "timestamp": "Jul 14, 2023 10:31:03 AM",
    "status": 404,
    "error": "Not Found",
    "message": "No message available",
    "path": "/actuatorxxx"
}
```

CommonsRequestLoggingFilter configuration

```
    @Bean
    public CommonsRequestLoggingFilter logFilter() {
        CommonsRequestLoggingFilter filter = new CommonsRequestLoggingFilter();
        filter.setIncludeQueryString(true);
        filter.setIncludeHeaders(false);
        filter.setBeforeMessagePrefix("PRE-REQUEST: ");
        filter.setAfterMessagePrefix("POST-REQUEST: ");
        return filter;
    }
```

1. tomcat/catalina debug logging, request logging, and configuring the server /error page to return stack trace etc is not giving any detail of why the route /actuator is not being resolved
2. neither is there any exception in the logs

Note also as I exec into the pod and use curl I am fairly certain this isn't related ngnix/ingress config in k8.

sanitised pod manifest extract

```
kind: Pod
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: my-app-sit-0
  generateName: my-app-sit-
  namespace: tdt-sit
  uid: d7f346e1-cbd7-4543-b4df-6da61defedae
  resourceVersion: '1263848088'
  creationTimestamp: '2023-07-08T14:18:33Z'
  labels:
    app: my-app-sit
    controller-revision-hash: my-app-sit-7d457f7dcb
    release: my-app-sit
    statefulset.kubernetes.io/pod-name: my-app-sit-0
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/psp: eks.privileged
    my-app.com/gitlab-project-id: '6778'
    my-app.com/gitlab-project-url: https://gitlab.my-app.com./my-app-deploy
spec:
  volumes:
    - name: aws-iam-token
      projected:
        sources:
          - serviceAccountToken:
              audience: sts.amazonaws.com
              expirationSeconds: 86400
              path: token
        defaultMode: 420
    - name: my-app-sit-mount
      persistentVolumeClaim:
        claimName: my-app-sit-mount-my-app-sit-0
    - name: secret-my-app-bqsakeys
      secret:
        secretName: my-app-bqsakeys
        defaultMode: 420
    - name: kube-api-access-7gvf6
      projected:
        sources:
          - serviceAccountToken:
              expirationSeconds: 3607
              path: token
          - configMap:
              name: kube-root-ca.crt
              items:
                - key: ca.crt
                  path: ca.crt
          - downwardAPI:
              items:
                - path: namespace
                  fieldRef:
                    apiVersion: v1
                    fieldPath: metadata.namespace
        defaultMode: 420
  containers:
    - name: my-app-container
      image: >-
        someimage
      command:
        - /bin/bash
        - '-c'
      args:
        - >-
          /opt/my-app-configure-n-start.sh && tail -F
          /opt/logs/my-app.log
      ports:
        - containerPort: 80
          protocol: TCP
      envFrom:
        - secretRef:
            name: my-app-credentials
      resources:
        limits:
          memory: 4Gi
        requests:
          cpu: 500m
          memory: 4Gi
      volumeMounts:
        - name: my-app-sit-mount
          mountPath: /mnt
        - name: kube-api-access-7gvf6
          readOnly: true
          mountPath: /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount
        - name: aws-iam-token
          readOnly: true
          mountPath: /var/run/secrets/eks.amazonaws.com/serviceaccount
      livenessProbe:
        exec:
          command:
            - /bin/sh
            - /opt/aux-scripts/my-app-liveness-check.sh
            - '8558'
        initialDelaySeconds: 180
        timeoutSeconds: 5
        periodSeconds: 10
        successThreshold: 1
        failureThreshold: 3
      terminationMessagePath: /dev/termination-log
      terminationMessagePolicy: File
      imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
      securityContext:
        capabilities:
          add:
            - SYS_ADMIN
            - DAC_READ_SEARCH
  restartPolicy: Always
  terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 30
  dnsPolicy: ClusterFirst
  serviceAccountName: my-app-sit
  serviceAccount: my-app-sit
  nodeName: ip-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx.my-app-node
  securityContext: {}
  imagePullSecrets:
    - name: regsecret
  hostname: my-app-sit-0
  subdomain: my-app-sit-svc
```

app-configure-n-start.sh script:

```
$APP_HOME/scripts/backgrounded-start > /dev/null 2> $APP_HOME/stderr.out &
```

Note above runs the start script on background

start script:

```
JAVA_OPTS="$APP_OTEL_AGENT_JAVA_COMMAND \
                                  $APP_JVM_HEAP_MIN $APP_JVM_HEAP_MAX -Xloggc:$APP_HOME/logs/gc.log -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCDateStamps\
                                  -XX:-PrintTenuringDistribution -XX:+PrintGCCause -XX:+PrintGCApplicationStoppedTime -XX:+UseGCLogFileRotation\
                                  -XX:NumberOfGCLogFiles=15 -XX:GCLogFileSize=2M -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError\
                                  -XX:HeapDumpPath=$APP_HOME/logs/ -XX:+DisableExplicitGC"

AKKA_CLASSPATH="$APP_HOME/lib/*:$APP_HOME/bin/*:$APP_HOME/config:$APP_HOME/lib/sigar/*:$APP_HOME/../*"

java $JAVA_OPTS -cp "$AKKA_CLASSPATH" -Dspring.profiles.active=<active-profile> au.com.my.app.akka.SpringApplication --spring.main.banner-mode=off
```

Can anyone suggest additional logging that I can add to illuminate what is going on? Or a possible cause?

Comment: What command are you using to run the application on k8s? Should be like `docker run -p 8080:8080 your-app`

Comment: @Mar-Z - given that for this I have executed into the pod to test I'm not sure I understand how the docker port mappings would come into play - as it is a local request on the running container?

Comment: Show your kubernetes manifests

Comment: Hi @Thomas - I've added a sanitised pod manifest. Note I've cut out other containers that make up the statefulset and left just the one in question.

Comment: Your pod config contains port 80 not 8080.

Comment: Hi @M.Deinum - I must be misunderstanding something. tomcat is listening on port 8080; and the request is curl http://localhost:8080/actuator and this command is run on the container itself. I may not even want to expose 8080 from outside the pod.

Comment: Does it actually bind to `localhost` and not the external IP address?

Comment: Same result with 127.0.0.1:8080/actuator if that helps clarify things.

Comment: Show your `my-app-configure-n-start.sh` script

Comment: Hi @Thomas - I've added the script that starts on the background. Note it starts the app on the background - and the container command is to start the app; and then tail the outputted log file.

Comment: Show the dockerfile to build the image

Comment: @M.Deinum - btw in terms of your question about if tomcat binds to localhost and not to an external ip address. I see this output in the logs `Register host [localhost] at domain [null] for service [StandardService[Tomcat]]` from logger `org.apache.catalina.mapper.MapperListener` - does this answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

The root cause of this issue was that locally I was running *without* the otel agent where-as in the k8 deploy $APP_OTEL_AGENT_JAVA_COMMAND added the following to the java command:

`-javaagent:/opt/lib/opentelemetry-javaagent.jar`

The version of otel used was 1.7.0 from 2021; and it interfered with tomcat/spring boot.

Upgrading to latest otel 1.28.0 resolved the issue.